# create dynamic PHP variables from a database

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, dynamic, morris.js

I have an array of names that I'd like to convert to variables. These are names of tests generated from a database (so if a new test is added a new index would be added to the array), our tests are updated on a regular basis so I don't want to hard-code my variables, I want to generate them dynamically.

I've tried this code:

```
$data = array();
foreach($tests as $v) {
    $$v = ${};
    array_push($data, $v);
}
```

My aim is to create the variables dynamically and then add to them for each instance of a test being taken, for example, if 6 people have had one of our instant tests, the variable 'instant' will have the value 6. Am I on the right track? Thanks!

***** UPDATE *****
Im trying to populate a morris.js chart using these variables, everything works when hard coded like so:

```
$pos = 0;
$neg = 0;
$pen = 0;
$cont = 0;
$misc = 0;
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($item['result'] === 'Positive') {
    $pos++;
    } elseif ($item['result'] === 'Negative') {
    $neg++;
    } elseif ($item['result'] === 'Pending') {
    $pen++;
    } elseif ($item['result'] === 'Contact the Clinic') {
     $cont++;
    } else {
    $misc++;
   }
 }

$res = array("Positive"=>$pos, "Negative"=>$neg, "Pending"=>$pen, "Contact the Clinic"=>$cont, "Misc"=>$misc);
$data = json_encode($res);
```

This gives me:
[image]

But im tryng to populate it dynamically from our databases so that if a new test / result set is added I don't have to go in and manually update the code, This is giving me data but no values as im not sure how to dynamically create variables based on the data:
/* Create dynamic variables: */

```
$vars = array();
foreach($tests as $k => $v) {
    array_push($vars, $v);
    $$v = extract($vars);
/* Loop through each instance and create a count for all matching instances */
    foreach($data as $item){
    if($item['name'] === $k){
    ${$v}++;
        }
    }
}
```

Is giving me the labels but with no value:

```
{"Positive","Negative","Pending","Contact the Clinic","Misc"}
```

Im currently using the Codeigniter (latest release) Cheers

Comment: Is that your actual code or is it pseudo-code?

Comment: That's the code I've tried, Its all I've found so far as most times variables are coded manually

Comment: Do you definitely need separate variables for these. Could you not just use an associative array (`$data[$v] = x;`)?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use mysqli, you could do it like this:

```
// your query stuff:
$stmt->query($query);
$data = $stmt->fetch_assoc();

// just for example data contains:
// array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Andy')

foreach($data as $field => $value) {
    ${$field} = $value;
}

// then output:
echo $name; // should output 'Andy';
```

Answer (score 0):

What about double dollar ? 
You can read it here
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Thanks, just tried the double $, still no values, ill update my question with code :)